# applcation.properties with maven jetty plugin

Tags: java, spring, ssl, jetty

I try to configure maven jetty plugin to run on 8443 (TLS) port.
I read much stuff about including official documentation.
This manual https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-security-settings suggest to configure it with XML files, but I didn't succeed to configure path for keystore there.
So I continued to `application.properties` way from here https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/
The problem is that jetty not recognizing `application.properties`.
The 8443 port is free, when I launching the application.

This is `application.properties`:

```
server.port = 8445
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = 123456
server.ssl.key-password = 123456
```

This is output of `mvn jetty:run`:

```
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=653ms
[INFO] 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
18:20:56.634 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams' with lowest search precedence
18:20:56.637 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with lowest search precedence
18:20:56.640 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'jndiProperties' with lowest search precedence
18:20:56.640 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
18:20:56.640 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
18:20:56.641 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [StubPropertySource@760604710 {name='servletConfigInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@4d1ff6b1}, StubPropertySource@1173837542 {name='servletContextInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@329548d0}, JndiPropertySource@805536380 {name='jndiProperties', properties=org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate@29b40b3}, MapPropertySource@2099541600 {name='systemProperties', properties={java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64, java.vm.version=25.121-b13, maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true, path.separator=:, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_121-b13, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/endorsed, os.arch=amd64, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, os.name=Linux, classworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, jetty.git.hash=82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8, java.library.path=/opt/oracle/instantclient:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.version=4.4.0-119-generic, user.home=/home/opshenichnikova, user.timezone=Europe/Moscow, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.8, java.class.path=/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar, user.name=opshenichnikova, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -e jetty:run, java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre, sun.arch.data.model=64, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.8.0_121, securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom, java.ext.dirs=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext, sun.boot.class.path=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/classes, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, maven.home=/usr/share/maven, file.separator=/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.desktop=gnome, sun.cpu.isalist=}}, SystemEnvironmentPropertySource@1701798620 {name='systemEnvironment', properties={PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient:/home/opshenichnikova/bin:/home/opshenichnikova/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121//bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121//bin:/opt/proclog/:/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/:/opt/cprocsp/sbin/amd64/:/opt/proclog, XAUTHORITY=/home/opshenichnikova/.Xauthority, XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus, XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop, GDMSESSION=ubuntu, MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path, GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus, TNS_ADMIN=/etc, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-EWkFlV90x8, DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity, JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient, UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1001/2482, QT4_IM_MODULE=xim, SESSION_MANAGER=local/IAS-WS-UX02:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2735,unix/IAS-WS-UX02:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2735, QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1, LOGNAME=opshenichnikova, JOB=unity-settings-daemon, PWD=/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity, DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db, IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1, LANGUAGE=en_US, WINDOWID=54525962, SHELL=/bin/bash, LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s, UNITY_HAS_3D_SUPPORT=true, GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar, INSTANCE=, J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle, GOPATH=/home/opshenichnikova/go:/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/islps/core/goLibs, OLDPWD=/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity, GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated, UPSTART_INSTANCE=, GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module, J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle, CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim, XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0, COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/, SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session, XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu, LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:, SHLVL=1, LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s, COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu, QT_IM_MODULE=ibus, UPSTART_JOB=unity7, JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/, TERM=xterm-256color, XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt, XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg, LANG=en_US.UTF-8, GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=, XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0, XDG_SESSION_ID=c2, XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11, DISPLAY=:0, UNITY_DEFAULT_PROFILE=unity, ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient, NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript, MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS= -e jetty:run, _=/usr/bin/mvn, GDM_LANG=en_US, XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/opshenichnikova, UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started, GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/opshenichnikova/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1, MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity, DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu, SESSION=ubuntu, USER=opshenichnikova, XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-, VTE_VERSION=4205, QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh, XDG_SEAT=seat0, NLSPATH=/opt/cprocsp/share/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N:/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5, XDG_VTNR=7, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001, HOME=/home/opshenichnikova, GNOME_KEYRING_PID=}}]
18:20:56.643 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with 'servletContextInitParams'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-04-09 18:20:57.058  INFO 17478 --- [           main] ru.ias.Main                              : Starting Main on IAS-WS-UX02 with PID 17478 (/home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity/target/classes started by opshenichnikova in /home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity)
2018-04-09 18:20:57.060  INFO 17478 --- [           main] ru.ias.Main                              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-09 18:20:57.113  INFO 17478 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1860f3be: startup date [Mon Apr 09 18:20:57 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-09 18:20:57.855  INFO 17478 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[INFO] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-09 18:20:57.938  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 828 ms
2018-04-09 18:20:58.189  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.192  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.192  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.192  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.192  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.192  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.525  INFO 17478 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1860f3be: startup date [Mon Apr 09 18:20:57 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-09 18:20:58.604  INFO 17478 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/admin/account/list],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<ru.ias.orm.Account> ru.ias.controllers.admin.AdminController.getAccounts()
2018-04-09 18:20:58.606  INFO 17478 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/admin/invoices],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<ru.ias.orm.Invoice> ru.ias.controllers.admin.InvoiceController.getInvoices(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-04-09 18:20:58.609  INFO 17478 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-04-09 18:20:58.610  INFO 17478 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-04-09 18:20:58.651  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.651  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.699  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-09 18:20:58.900  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-04-09 18:20:58.916  INFO 17478 --- [           main] ru.ias.Main                              : Started Main in 2.266 seconds (JVM running for 5.815)
[INFO] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[INFO] Scavenging every 660000ms
[INFO] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-04-09 18:20:58.983  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-04-09 18:20:58.998  INFO 17478 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 15 ms
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@165e389b{/,file:///home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity/target/webapp-tmp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity/target/webapp-tmp/}
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.005 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-09T18:20:59+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/669M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run (default-cli) on project bot-integrity: Failure: Address already in use -> [Help 1]
```

The structure of the application is:

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── ru
│   │   │       └── ias
│   │   │           └── Main.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
```

Th pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.ias</groupId>
    <artifactId>bot-integrity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>bot-integrity</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
         <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
           <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--jettyXml>jetty.xml,jetty-ssl.xml,jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>-->
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                            true
                        </allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>botintegrity</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <!--<repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>-->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!--<repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>-->
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot why are you making things overly complex. Spirng Boot will launch the Jetty container for you however you are trying to do it yourself. Don't do that let Spring Boot run the application. Remove your plugins from the `plugins` section and add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. That will create an executable jar that you can launch with `java -jar <your-jar-name>` or by simply running the `main` method from your IDE.

Comment: But I will not able to use mvn jetty:run...

Comment: Use `mvn spring-boot:run` instead. Work with the framework not around it. Also the `server.*` properties are useless if you don't use an embedded Jetty instance which Spring Boot can control, if you use the maven plugin spring boot doesn't control the servlet container.

Comment: OK, it makes me step forward. Can you put it as answer? I will check it as right. And, I have next issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748409/spring-controllers-arent-response-to-https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out whether your jar file after packaging contains resources that you require? Checkout the `target/classes` directory. If it does, then it's something clearly wrong with jetty-plugin configuration.

AFAIK in order to bundle resources you have to use maven resource plugin and declare these resources. Here's [link to documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

Usage is pretty simple

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It includes other resources, actually, I have hibernate config there... I tried your code, it don't take effect.