# Provide keystore to jetty sslContextFactory

Tags: spring, maven, ssl, jetty

I use maven jetty plugin.
I need run it on TLS 8443.
I try follow the manual, but I need to configure every thing from XML.
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html
In parallel I try, to configure it via `application.properties` as I asked here: [applcation.properties with maven jetty plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736945/applcation-properties-with-maven-jetty-plugin/49737153#49737153)

When I run `mvn -e jetty:run` I get:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration$1: class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setKeyStore(class java.lang.String). Found setters for java.security.KeyStore
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.ServerSupport.applyXmlConfigurations(ServerSupport.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.ServerSupport.applyXmlConfigurations(ServerSupport.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.applyJettyXml(AbstractJettyMojo.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:426)
    ... 24 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setKeyStore(java.lang.String)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:540)
        ... 33 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: TYPE
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:553)
        ... 33 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: KeyStore
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:568)
        ... 33 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:597)
        ... 33 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.KeyStore.<init>(java.lang.String)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:640)
        ... 33 more
```

This is `jetty-ssl.xml`:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStore"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/data/jetty/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">123456</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStore"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/data/jetty/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">123456</Set>
  </New>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add a SSL Connector with no protocol factories              -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call  name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
            </Item>-->
          </Array>
        </Arg>

        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="8443" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Create a TLS specific HttpConfiguration based on the        -->
  <!-- common HttpConfiguration defined in jetty.xml               -->
  <!-- Add a SecureRequestCustomizer to extract certificate and    -->
  <!-- session information                                         -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer">
          <Arg name="sniHostCheck" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck" default="true"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsMaxAgeSeconds" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsMaxAgeSeconds" default="-1"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsIncludeSubdomains" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsIncludeSubdomains" default="false"/></Arg>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>

</Configure>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.ias</groupId>
    <artifactId>bot-integrity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>bot-integrity</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
         <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
           <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyXml>jetty.xml,jetty-ssl.xml,jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                            true
                        </allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>botintegrity</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <!--<repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>-->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!--<repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>-->
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Can we see your jetty-maven-plugin declaration in your pom too?

Comment: I added pom contents